# How do I use ActiveRecord Encryption in a Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, encryption, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I have a Sinatra app which runs ActiveRecord by using the `activerecord` and `sinatra-activerecord` gems. I would like to use ActiveRecord encryption, but the [ActiveRecord Encryption guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html) assumes that I have a Rails app and specifies how to add the required encryption keys to the Rails credentials file. As this is not a Rails app, how do I specify an alternate keystore for ActiveRecord to use?

Specifically the error I am seeing is:

```
ActiveRecord::Encryption::Errors::Configuration:
        key_derivation_salt is not configured. Please configure it via credential active_record_encryption.key_derivation_salt or by setting config.active_record.encryption.key_derivation_salt
```

So I think that it is running correctly, I just don't know how to configure it without the Rails credentials file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ActiveRecord::Encryption.configure(
  primary_key:         xxx,
  deterministic_key:   yyy,
  key_derivation_salt: zzz
)
```

Looks undocumented, but [found in the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d921f203c356a0d6902a3f75067f08993f4e33fa/activerecord/lib/active_record/encryption/configurable.rb#L20).